# Twig how to interpolate within JSON

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to remove Unicode charactes from within a string.

```
    {% include 'components/accordion.twig' with {
      this: {
        id: program.slug,
        active: (loop.index == 1) ? true : false
      }
    } only %}
  {% endfor %}
```

basically what I'm trying to achieve is to

```
{% include 'components/accordion.twig' with {
          this: {
            id: "{{ programs.slug | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') }}"
            active: (loop.index == 1) ? true : false
          }
        } only %}
{% endfor %}
```

the problem is that `programs.slug` returns `"aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie"`I'm trying to remove `%e2%80%8b` so I have `"aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-scrie"` via the `convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')` How can I go about doing that?

Comment: "*Removing unicode characters*"? You realize JSON has to be utf8 encoded, right?

Comment: @Sherif I updated my post

Comment: `%e2%80%8b` is urlencoded which means that when decoded it represents `U+E2808B` or really `U+200B` which is a **zero-width-space** character. Stripping it out by mangling the encoding is about as circuitous as it gets.

Comment: @Sherif so how can I go about sanitizing that string? I'm getting the error ```SyntaxError: '#aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie' is not a valid selector```

Comment: The question obviously isn't how. `str_replace` can do that. The real question is why do you want to delete it?

Comment: but if I remove `%e2%80%8b`the toggle works

Comment: Again, `%e2%80%8b` is obviously URL encoded. You probably got that encoded value from `$_GET` or some other url-encoded mechanism. Running it through `urldecode` encodes it back to valid utf8.

Comment: `var_dump(urldecode('#aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie'))` gives you `string(56) "#aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-​scrie"` notice that it's **56** and not 53, however. That's because there's a zero-width-space in there. If you want it removed: `var_dump(str_replace("\u{200b}", "", urldecode('#aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-%e2%80%8bscrie')))` and that gives you `string(53) "#aria-c-senior-citizens-rent-increase-exemption-scrie"`

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
{% include 'components/accordion.twig' with {
  this: {
    id: program.slug | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1'),
    active: (loop.index == 1) ? true : false
  }
} only %}
```

because `{{ }}` is equivalent to `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in timber [Make functions available in Twig](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
 /**
     * Adds functionality to Twig.
     *
     * @param \Twig\Environment $twig The Twig environment.
     * @return \Twig\Environment
     */
function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    // Adding functions as filters.
    $twig->addFilter( new Timber\Twig_Filter( 'url_decode', 'url_decode' ) );

    return $twig;
}

function url_decode( $text ) {
    return  urldecode($text);
}
```

I had to decode the `programs.slug` so I created a function and pass it in the twig template as follow using [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
 id: function('url_decode', program.slug),
```